# Finding moving average by attribute by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using the following table structure as example: City Key,  Invoice Date, Profit
I need to find moving average for each city using last 5 days and following 5 days.

Am I using the right script ?

```
SELECT  [City Key],[Invoice Date Key], AVG([Profit])
OVER(ORDER BY [City Key],[Invoice Date Key] ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND 5 FOLLOWING) AS d10_Mov_avg

FROM Fact.Sale
ORDER BY [City Key], [Invoice Date Key]
```

The script is working but
I tried to double check in Excel and got different results, but I don't understand why and I am wondering if I get wrong result because of data, not script itself.

Comment: We need sample data and expected results to comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `PARTITION BY`:

```
SELECT [City Key],[Invoice Date Key],
       AVG([Profit]) OVER (PARTITION BY [City Key]
                           ORDER BY [Invoice Date Key]
                           ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND 5 FOLLOWING
                          ) AS d10_Mov_avg

FROM Fact.Sale
ORDER BY [City Key], [Invoice Date Key];
```

This also assumes that you have a day for every city.  If not, using window functions for this is challenging.